# TypeError: unhashable type on new computer but not old

Tags: python, numpy

I just got a new computer, and now a bunch of my python scripts dont work because they return the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple1.py", line 65, in <module>
    time = np.array(simple_trajectories[0][:,0]) 
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Several commenters have helped to identify that the error arises because simple_trajectories[0] is a dictionary on the new computer and a numpy.ndarray on the old computer.

Is there a way to figure out why this is happening? or if not, is there a simple fix to change it back to the numpy ndarray form?

both computers are using python 2.7.12 and ubuntu 16.04

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The full code is pasted here:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sys
sys.path[:0] = ['..']

import gillespy

class Simple1(gillespy.Model):
    """
    This is a simple example for mass-action degradation of species S.
    """

    def __init__(self, parameter_values=None):

        # Initialize the model.
        gillespy.Model.__init__(self, name="simple1")

        # Parameters
        k1 = gillespy.Parameter(name='k1', expression=0.3)
        self.add_parameter(k1)

        # Species
        S = gillespy.Species(name='S', initial_value=100)
        self.add_species(S)

        # Reactions
        rxn1 = gillespy.Reaction(
                name = 'S degradation',
                reactants = {S:1},
                products = {},
                rate = k1 )
        self.add_reaction(rxn1)
        self.timespan(np.linspace(0,20,101))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Here, we create the model object.
    # We could pass new parameter values to this model here if we wished.
    simple_model = Simple1()

    # The model object is simulated with the StochKit solver, and 25 
    # trajectories are returned.
    num_trajectories = 250
    simple_trajectories = simple_model.run(number_of_trajectories = num_trajectories)




    # PLOTTING


    # here, we will plot all trajectories with the mean overlaid
    from matplotlib import gridspec

    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)


    ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])

    # extract time values
    time = np.array(simple_trajectories[0][:,0]) 

    # extract just the trajectories for S into a numpy array
    S_trajectories = np.array([simple_trajectories[i][:,1] for i in xrange(num_trajectories)]).T

    #plot individual trajectories
    ax0.plot(time, S_trajectories, 'gray', alpha = 0.1)

    #plot mean
    ax0.plot(time, S_trajectories.mean(1), 'k--', label = "Mean S")

    #plot min-max
    ax0.plot(time,S_trajectories.min(1), 'b--', label = "Minimum S")
    ax0.plot(time,S_trajectories.max(1), 'r--', label = "Maximum S")

    ax0.legend()
    ax0.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax0.set_ylabel('Species S Count')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Pip Freeze from old Computer

```
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
Babel==1.3
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
billiard==3.3.0.22
boto==2.38.0
celery==3.1.20
chardet==2.3.0
configparser==3.5.0
cryptography==1.2.3
cvxopt==1.1.4
cycler==0.9.0
Cython==0.23.4
debtcollector==1.3.0
decorator==4.0.6
ecdsa==0.13
entrypoints==0.2.2
enum34==1.1.2
funcsigs==0.4
functools32==3.2.3.post2
future==0.16.0
gillespy==1.0
gmpy==1.17
h5py==2.6.0
html5lib==0.999
idna==2.0
ipaddress==1.0.16
ipykernel==4.5.2
ipython==5.1.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==5.2.2
iso8601==0.1.11
jdcal==1.0
Jinja2==2.8
joblib==0.9.4
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.4.0
jupyter-console==5.0.0
jupyter-core==4.2.1
keyring==7.3
keystoneauth1==2.4.1
kombu==3.0.33
lxml==3.5.0
mailer==0.7
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==1.5.1
mistune==0.7.3
monotonic==0.6
mpmath==0.19
msgpack-python==0.4.6
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4
nbconvert==4.2.0
nbformat==4.2.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0
netaddr==0.7.18
netifaces==0.10.4
nolds==0.3.2
nose==1.3.7
notebook==4.2.3
numexpr==2.4.3
numpy==1.13.1
openpyxl==2.3.0
oslo.i18n==3.5.0
oslo.serialization==2.4.0
oslo.utils==3.8.0
pandas==0.17.1
paramiko==1.16.0
pathlib2==2.1.0
patsy==0.4.1
pbr==1.8.0
PeakUtils==1.0.3
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==3.1.2
positional==1.0.1
prettytable==0.7.2
prompt-toolkit==1.0.9
ptyprocess==0.5
py==1.4.31
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
pyeeg==0.4.0
pyentrp==0.3.0
pyglet==1.1.4
Pygments==2.1.3
pygobject==3.20.0
PyMySQL==0.7.2
PyOpenGL==3.0.2
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
pyparsing==2.0.3
pysb==1.2.2
pytest==2.8.7
python-apt==1.1.0b1
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-libsbml==5.13.0
python-memcached==1.53
python-novaclient==3.3.1
pytz==2014.10
pyurdme==1.1.1
PyYAML==3.11
pyzmq==15.2.0
qtconsole==4.2.1
requests==2.9.1
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy==0.19.1
scour==0.32
seaborn==0.7.1
SecretStorage==2.1.3
selenium==3.0.2
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.8.1
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.11
statsmodels==0.6.1
stevedore==1.12.0
sympy==0.7.6.1
tables==3.2.2
terminado==0.6
tornado==4.2.1
traitlets==4.3.1
unity-lens-photos==1.0
urllib3==1.13.1
VTK==5.10.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
widgetsnbextension==1.2.6
wrapt==1.8.0
xlrd==0.9.4
xlwt==0.7.5
```

Pip Freeze from New Computer

```
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
Babel==1.3
backports-abc==0.5
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
billiard==3.3.0.22
bleach==2.0.0
boto==2.38.0
celery==3.1.20
certifi==2017.4.17
chardet==2.3.0
configparser==3.5.0
cryptography==1.2.3
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.23.4
debtcollector==1.3.0
decorator==4.0.6
ecdsa==0.13
entrypoints==0.2.3
enum34==1.1.2
funcsigs==0.4
functools32==3.2.3.post2
gillespy==1.0
h5py==2.7.0
html5lib==0.999999999
idna==2.0
ipaddress==1.0.16
ipykernel==4.6.1
ipython==5.4.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==6.0.0
iso8601==0.1.11
Jinja2==2.9.6
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.1.0
jupyter-console==5.1.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0
keyring==7.3
keystoneauth1==2.4.1
kombu==3.0.33
lxml==3.5.0
mailer==0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==2.0.2
mistune==0.7.4
monotonic==0.6
msgpack-python==0.4.6
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4
nbconvert==5.2.1
nbformat==4.3.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0
netaddr==0.7.18
netifaces==0.10.4
notebook==5.0.0
numpy==1.13.1
oslo.i18n==3.5.0
oslo.serialization==2.4.0
oslo.utils==3.8.0
pandas==0.17.0
pandocfilters==1.4.1
paramiko==1.16.0
pathlib2==2.3.0
pbr==1.8.0
PeakUtils==1.1.0
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
positional==1.0.1
prettytable==0.7.2
prompt-toolkit==1.0.14
ptyprocess==0.5
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
Pygments==2.2.0
pygobject==3.20.0
PyMySQL==0.7.11
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-apt==1.1.0b1
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-libsbml==5.15.0
python-memcached==1.53
python-novaclient==3.3.1
pytz==2014.10
pyurdme==1.1.1
PyYAML==3.11
pyzmq==16.0.2
qtconsole==4.3.0
requests==2.9.1
scandir==1.5
scipy==0.19.1
scour==0.32
seaborn==0.8
SecretStorage==2.1.3
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.11
stevedore==1.12.0
terminado==0.6
testpath==0.3.1
tornado==4.5.1
traitlets==4.3.2
unity-lens-photos==1.0
urllib3==1.13.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==2.0.0
wrapt==1.8.0
```

I will bold the differences

Comment: can you post the full code? we don't have enough here to help you. what is `simple_trajectories`?

Comment: all of my scripts get this error when dealing with lists in the new computer

Comment: Compare the output of "pip freeze" from the two computer.  Perhaps you have different versions of numpy.

Comment: Numpy is the same. but i will make a list of the differences

Comment: Can you break down the line with the exception to see what exactly is causing the error? Is it the indexing, or the creation of the numpy array? I don't know anything at all about the `gillespy` module you're using, so I sort of assume the error is coming from somewhere in its internals. Is the exception traceback you showed complete?

Comment: What do you get when you issue: `pip show gillespy` (doesn't matter on which computer)

Comment: That is the full traceback. Gillespy is a python package for doign stochastic simulations. it is creating a list of dictionaries fine. the error arises when i try to call from one of the dictonaries.

Comment: pip show gillespy provides: ---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: gillespy
Version: 1.0
Summary: Python interface to the Gillespie StochKit2 solvers
Home-page: http://www.github.com/JohnAbel/GillesPy
Author: John H. Abel, Brian Drawert, Andreas Hellander
Author-email: ['jhabel01@gmail.com', 'briandrawert@gmail.com', 'andreas.hellander@gmail.com']
License: GPL
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: numpy, matplotlib, scipy
Classifiers:

Comment: So `trajectories[0]` is a dictionary?  If so, that explains the error.  You can't use a slice as the key of a dictionary, which is what `trajectories[0][:,0]` is trying to do.  (Are you sure you copied the *complete* error message?  I would expect to see `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`.)

Comment: 1. i am sure it is the complete error message. From a different script with gillespy:  phoenix@phoenix-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-15m-bp0xx:~/Desktop/Figures/DeterAllSpeciesFig$ python howlongdoweneedtorun.py
2017-07-22 21:33:23.872713
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "howlongdoweneedtorun.py", line 1783, in <module>
    MeanAlk3 =     np.mean(([set1_trajectories[0][86400:129600,1]])[0])
TypeError: unhashable type
phoenix@phoenix-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-15m-bp0xx:~/Desktop/Figures/DeterAllSpeciesFig$ ^

Comment: I am less sure it is a dictionary. these scripts all work perfectly on my old computer. let me see if it is a dictionary in the old computer

Comment: So it looks like the root cause is that set1_trajectories[0] is a dictionary in the new computer and a numpy.ndarray in the old computer.  

is there any reason that should be so, or an easy fix?

Comment: Try `    simple_trajectories = simple_model.run(number_of_trajectories = num_trajectories, show_labels=False)`

Comment: When `show_labels` is True, the return value of the `run()` method is a list of dictionaries.  Apparently the examples are based on `show_labels=False`.

Comment: P.S. When I said I expected to see `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`, it was because I checked it using Python 3.  In Python 2, the error doesn't include the type of the offending index.

Comment: Thank you so much this solved the problem. It looks like they did an update on gillespy a month ago without changing the edition number, and in that update i guess they changed the default.  So i downloaded an older version and now all my scripts work again. 

can you tell me how you figured this out? like which files did you look at?  I am trying to get better at solving these issues on my own

Comment: The source is here: https://github.com/JohnAbel/gillespy/blob/master/gillespy/gillespy.py; I just worked my way backward from the `run()` method of `gillespy.Model` until I found the lines that create the actual return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the argument `show_labels=False` to the `run()` call:

```
simple_trajectories = simple_model.run(number_of_trajectories=num_trajectories, show_labels=False)
```

When `show_labels` is True, the return value of the `run()` method is a list of dictionaries.  When the argument is False, a list of numpy arrays is returned. Apparently the examples are based on `show_labels=False`.

You might not be able to depend on the version number of `gillespy`; it depends on how you installed it.  In the call of `setup()` in the file `setup.py`, the version has been at "1.0" for a while.  Changes have been made without changing the version.  In particular, when the `show_labels` argument was added, the version was not changed.